# Charges for consumer accounts in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, shared

Hope you are doing well.

Database created in consumer account from share is read only, so consumer won't have any storage charges right.

I have one doubt here, let say consumer created a materialized views from that database and then does the consumer incur storage charges because materialized views stores result set.

Regards,

Sudhakar

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a Materialized View on Shared Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#creating-a-materialized-view-on-shared-data)

> Note
>
> **Remember that maintaining materialized views will consume credits. When you create a materialized view on someone else’s shared table, the changes to that shared table will result in charges to you as your materialized view is maintained**

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views will incur additional costs based on storage and compute resources. The updates to base table can consume significant resources, resulting in credit usage. This is also applicable on the shared database created from a share in a consumer account, as a Materialized view created has to be maintained.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#creating-a-materialized-view-on-shared-data

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#maintenance-costs-for-materialized-views

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#viewing-costs